# Efficient counting and grouping in SQL:1999

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the number of records logged against certain objects during certain times. I need to return the Primary Key `Key` and Friendly Name `FullName` against the number of records which are logged against each object. All of these are in the same table `EVENTS`.

This is easily done for `Key` OR `FullName` using:

```
SELECT FullName, COUNT(*) AS "RecordNum"
FROM TableA
WHERE RecordTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP Start AND TIMESTAMP Finish
GROUP BY FullName
```

If I want to return both using

```
SELECT FullName, Key, COUNT(*) AS "RecordNum"
FROM TableA
WHERE RecordTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP Start AND TIMESTAMP Finish
GROUP BY FullName
```

I get the error

> Select Element Key is invalid because a column reference is not contained in either a summary function or the GROUP BY clause.

I can create the top table as `TableB` and then join this to `TableA`:

```
SELECT TableA.FullName, TableA.Key, TableB."RecordNum"
FROM TableA INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Key, COUNT(*) AS "RecordNum"
    FROM TableA
    WHERE RecordTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP Start AND TIMESTAMP Finish
    GROUP BY FullName) As TableB On TableA.Key = TableB.Key
ORDER BY TableB.RecordNum DESC
```

This seems a pretty long winded way about doing the query though, as it's all contained within the same table. Can I use the `GROUP BY` clause and return the `Key` and `FullName` columns without resorting to an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.\

Comment: It's a part of a software package which has a database based upon SQL:1999 aka SQL 3.

Comment: That's the only thing you can do with SQL:1999

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I will just have to make sure I am careful with picking time periods to keep the load manageable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can't find the appropriate tag. I may just be blind but I can't see it for SQL:1999 or SQL 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a window function:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.FullName) AS "RecordNum"
FROMT TableA a
WHERE a.RecordTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP a.Start AND TIMESTAMP a.Finish
ORDER BY "RecordNum";
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to any of the functionality Microsoft has added since 1999.

Comment: @Flash_Steel: it's **not** Microsoft that added window functions - it's the ANSI committee for the SQL standard (Oracle actually had them back in '99)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, okay. I only ever heard of it with respect to Transact-SQL. However I still don't think it is a part of the SQL:1999 standard and either way, I can't use the keyword using this software unfortunately.